# How to call the result of a consult and put it in a Textfield? Mysql + Java

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

my textfield is called **pruebamax**

With this function I make the connection with the database

```
public ResultSet getmax() {
    ResultSet r = null;
    try {
        String sql = "select count(*) as Cantidad from tbl_padre";
        System.out.println(sql);
        Statement st = cx.createStatement();
        r = st.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println(st.executeQuery(sql));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tmrptryone.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return r;
}
```

his method in the event of a button, with this method I want to print in the textfield the data I receive from the database but I got an error.

```
 public void actualizatext() {
    try {
        ResultSet r = mrp.getmax();
        if (r.next()) {
            String ID = r.getString("Cantidad");
            pruebamax.setText(ID);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you got? Please post stacktrace as well.

Comment: Does not print the value I want in the text field, does not print anything to me in the text field

Comment: I do not know if this is how the syntax works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I don't know what **pruebamax** means but the SQL statement you used:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cantidad FROM tbl_padre";
```

is specifically used to **count** the total number of records currently maintained within the specified database table (**tbl_padre**). The value from that count will be held in the specified temporary field named: **Cantidad**. When you Use the SQL **COUNT** statement you are not going to be returned a String data type value. You will be expected to try and acquire a Integer value.

It ***will not*** acquire a value from your table **ID** field as what it looks like you expect.

To properly retrieve the records count from your applied SQL string then it should be used in this fashion:

```
int count = 0;
try {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rCount FROM tbl_padre";
    Statement st = cx.createStatement();
    ResultSet r = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while (r.next()) {
        count = r.getInt("rCount");
    }
    r.close();
    st.close();
    // Close your DB connection as well if desired.
    // yourConnection.close();

    //To apply this value to your JTextField:
    pruebamax.setText(String.valueOf(count));

    System.out.println("Total number of records in the tbl_padre " +
                       " table is: " + count);
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Try not to use actual table field names for temporary field names.*

If you want to be more specific with your count then your SQL statement must be more specific as well. For example, let's assume that we want to count the number of records maintained in our table where a field named **Age** contains a value which is greater than **30** years old, our sql statement would look like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rCount FROM tbl_padre WHERE Age > 30";
```

You will of course have noticed the use of the SQL **WHERE** clause.